# Exchange DAG 2013 force node to keep mounted database

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, windows-cluster, dag

Please do help us with this critical issue.

We have 2 node DAG, one of the MB server has issues on the physical host itself and keeps hanging. All the databases has copies on 2 MB servers. But when this MB2 server gets hanged the database shows dismounted. It doesn't switch over to MB1 which should be happening. We have to restart the MB2 to get the database up and running or wait for long time to move to MB1.

We currently have plans to built another node and gradually remove the faulty MB2.

Please instruct us on how to prevent the current databases which is on MB1 not to move to MB2 and stay in MB1 itself

Awaiting kind response on this regard

Thanks in Advance

-Sanjai

Comment: Depending on the amount of data being replicated from MB1 to MB2 the process might be still on-going when the MB2 fails. Did you have a look at the Exchange logs? Windows Logs?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer if you set the "ActivationPreference" correctly and point them to the "healthy" server. Exchange 2013 shouldn´t do an automatically "rebalance" as Exchange 2016 do (see [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/06/16/dag-activation-preference-behavior-change-in-exchange-server-2016-cu2/)). Then an issue related to the "faulty" server shouldn´t cause any issues (disconnect) for your users.

> The Activation preference number Displays the activation preference
>   number. This is used as part of Active Manager's best copy selection
>   process, and it is used to balance the DAG by redistributing active
>   mailbox databases throughout the DAG via the DAG's
>   PreferenceMoveFrequency property. This property defines the frequency
>   (measured in time) when the Microsoft Exchange Replication service
>   rebalances database copies by performing a lossless switchover that
>   activates the copy with an activation preference number of 1. The
>   value for activation preference is a number equal to or greater than
>   1, where 1 is at the top of the preference order. The number can't be
>   larger than the number of copies of the mailbox database.

For more see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd351151(v=exchg.160).aspx) or [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd298104(v=exchg.160).aspx).

However having a faulty Exchange Mailbox (MB) server in your DAG might cause corruptions and I would quickly fix that.